# Linq how to find max repeat items?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object (ProductInfo).
ProductInfo contains an id, name, and an option.

Imagine this sample, i have this

```
     ProductInfo Id => 1, Name => XXX, Option = A
     ProductInfo Id => 1, Name => XXX, Option = B
     ProductInfo Id => 2, Name => DEB, Option = A
     ProductInfo Id => 2, Name => DEB, Option = B
     ProductInfo Id => 2, Name => DEB, Option = C
     ProductInfo Id => 3, Name => ZZZ, Option = D
     ....
....
```

We see we have 2 time the option A AND B for product 1 and 2.
My goal will be to obtain the max repeat item for each product in the list.

i would like to obtain as result this :
Id = 1, Name = XXX = A, count = 2
Id =2, Name = DEB, count = 2

How i can do that ?
thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried to find an answer for this max-repeating question, either with the help of google or on your own?

Comment: Ini this case wouldn't ID = 2, Name = DEB and count = 3?

Comment: I don't get why you have Count = 2 in both cases.  And what `Name = XXX = A` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do this code:

```
 var list = new List<ProductInfo> {
                new ProductInfo { Id = 1, Name = "XXX", Option = "A"},
                new ProductInfo { Id = 1, Name = "XXX", Option = "B" },
                new ProductInfo { Id = 2, Name = "DEB", Option = "A" },
                new ProductInfo { Id = 2, Name = "DEB", Option = "B"},
                new ProductInfo { Id = 2, Name = "DEB", Option = "C" },
                new ProductInfo { Id = 3, Name = "ZZZ", Option = "D" }

            };

            var x = from p in list
                    group p by new { p.Id, p.Name, p.Option } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = g.Key.Id,
                        Name = g.Key.Name,
                        Count = list.Count(m => m.Name == g.Key.Name)
                    };
            var t = x.Distinct();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` on the Name and Id  parameter. Sorry read that wrong at first.

Comment: Hello all sorry for some mistake in my question ! Thanks to jeric cruz for the help ...